# Proper way to use getTile() function in google maps

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, google-maps

I'm storing markers in database using tiles id.

So that when a certain tile is displayed on a map all the markers that this tile contain are

requested and displayed too.

So i finally created a code that didn't  work correctly. It didn't request all the needed

tiles. To be more accurate it requested only one tile each time i moved the map.

```
     ServerFetchMapType.prototype.tileSize = new google.maps.Size(256,256);

     ServerFetchMapType.prototype.maxZoom = 100;

     ServerFetchMapType.prototype.name = "Server Tile #s";

     ServerFetchMapType.prototype.alt  = "Server Data Tile Map Type";

ServerFetchMapType.prototype.getTile = function(coord, zoom, ownerDocument){

  if(zoom>10){

  var tileId=this.getAddrLatLng(coord,zoom);

  if(isTileAlreadyLoaded(tileId)){
    return ;
  }

  ServerFetchedTiles[tileId] = true;

  var url = "markerRequestPageJson.php?tileNumber=";
  var json;
   $.getJSON(url+tileId,function(json){
    // this is where we can loop through the results in the json object
        var _item;
        var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow;

        $.each(json, function(i,_item){
            var point = new google.maps.LatLng(
              parseFloat(_item.lat),
              parseFloat(_item.lng));
            var html = _item.id + "<br/>";
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            map: map,
            position: point
          });

          markerClusterer.addMarker(marker);
          bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infoWindow, html);
        });
});

 }
 return;

};
```

But in the end i made some changes and it worked as it should:

```
     ServerFetchMapType.prototype.tileSize = new google.maps.Size(256,256);

     ServerFetchMapType.prototype.maxZoom = 100;

     ServerFetchMapType.prototype.name = "Server Tile #s";

     ServerFetchMapType.prototype.alt  = "Server Data Tile Map Type";

ServerFetchMapType.prototype.getTile = function(coord, zoom, ownerDocument){

  if(zoom>10){

  var tileId=this.getAddrLatLng(coord,zoom);

  if(isTileAlreadyLoaded(tileId)){
    return ;
  }

  ServerFetchedTiles[tileId] = true;

  var div = ownerDocument.createElement('DIV');

  var url = "markerRequestPageJson.php?tileNumber=";
  var json;
   $.getJSON(url+tileId,function(json){
    // this is where we can loop through the results in the json object
        var _item;
        var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow;

        $.each(json, function(i,_item){
            var point = new google.maps.LatLng(
              parseFloat(_item.lat),
              parseFloat(_item.lng));
            var html = _item.id + "<br/>";
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            map: map,
            position: point
          });

          markerClusterer.addMarker(marker);
          bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infoWindow, html);
        });
});
  return div;
 }
 return;

};
```

My question: Is it a proper solution?

Comment: More information you can find here:http://kashey.ru/maps/ajax-loading-as-tiles/

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you're trying to do here; but why do you have to bother clicking which tile is loading?

You could just give the Marker{ position: the_position, ... } and the Maps API should take care of displaying it, no?

Comment: Tiles are used to request markers that are currently in viewport. And markers are displayed using marker cluster.